# Blank page while launching PHP File

Tags: php, twitter

I'm managing a Twitter Bot that tweets a electronic music every 30mn, or since my last update (made at 12:00 France Time) the bot doesn't tweet anymore and also, when I run the php path, that were totally functionnal before, I land on a totally blank page and nothing happens.

Here's the beginning of the code (it's 2345 lines long so the beginning should do it)

```
<?php

// Inclusion du fichier API OAuth Twitter
require_once('TwitterOAuth.php');

// Définition des codes API Twitter
define('CONSUMER_KEY', 'XXX');
define('CONSUMER_SECRET', 'XXX');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN', 'XXX');
define('ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET', 'XXX'); 

// Connexion OAuth Twitter
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);

// Définition des messages à tweeter automatiquement
$tweetMsg = array(

'【DUBSTEP】 Guillotine - Bandwagon https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ppQ2k6sAFDo',
'【DUBSTEP】 Urbanstep - Alternation (ft. Micah Martin) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MZcuUOieiWA',
'【DUBSTEP】 Dabin & Koven - Revenant https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2OygcJ3UV8',
'【DUBSTEP】 Extra Terra - Infinity https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ON3144uk2Tk',
```

I've paid attention and made no apostrophe or comas errors. I've hidden my token for privacy. Any help will be a huge relief for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything in your server's error log? Nothing in the code that you have posted explicitly outputs anything, so hard to tell.

Comment: Okay, I found out the problem, my FTP were sending the files in text mode